# How can make responsive design for phone and tablet in react native?

Tags: react-native

Explanation: I am learning a React Native framework. I installed the application in my phone. It's working fine. I want to know how react native will manage the design when device density changed.

Similarly, In Native Android we provides the different resource for the phone devices and tablet devices. We also manage the layout file for the tablet and phone for portrait and landscape. When our application run on the device whether it a phone or tablet it will automatically get their best suited resources according to the tablet or phone.

I have little bit stuck when i starting the development in react native.

How react native handle the text size?

How it can manage the design screen when it's running on the phone or tablet?

How it can manage the images resources in different density devices?

Is there any strategy where we can manage everything like Native Android?

Please, help me solve out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox for this.

for example.

flex: 1 is full width
flex: 0.5 is half

so you can do something like this.

All dimensions in React Native are unitless, and represent density-independent pixels

For images you can do imagename@2x imagename@3x 
details are here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html

```js
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }} />
  <View style={{ flex: 0.5 }} />
</View>
```

This will create a row with 2 columns in it. and this will be responsive.

Comment: If i have 5 images with same name then how can i mange same image with same size in phone and tablet and how can i give the same font size for phone and tablet?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the docs on [PixelRatio](https://reactnative.dev/docs/pixelratio), there are several methods to deal with different dpis and fontScalings.

Additionally you might want to look into https://github.com/marudy/react-native-responsive-screen which

> is a small library that provides 2 simple methods so that React Native
> developers can code their UI elements fully responsive. No media
> queries needed.